# Scrollview doesn't work when I keep adding labels to a view

Tags: ios, swift

I have this Swift 4 app, and have a view controller that looks like this

```
View
    Safe Area
    Scroll View
        Stack View
            Label
            View
            Contacts View
            View
                Button1
            View
                Button2
    Bottom View
```

I'm given an array of contacts, and I want to create a label for each contact and add it to `Contacts View`.

```
 var labelY = 48

 for con in contacts {

        let aux = try self.contactStore.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: con, keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor])

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 24, y: labelY, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "\(aux.givenName) \(aux.familyName)"
        contactsView.addSubview(label)

        labelY = labelY + 24

 }
```

The problem that I have is that when I have a lot of contacts, they get cut after 5 o so, and I can't scroll.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The most logical thing to do is:

- add a vertical stack view as a subview of your `Contacts View`
- constrain it to all 4 sides of `Contacts View`, using however much "padding" you want
- then add each label as an arranged subview of that stack view

This will cause the `Contacts View` to grow vertically with each added label.

Note that you don't need to set frames for those labels:

```
for con in contacts {

    let aux = try self.contactStore.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: con, keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor])

    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "\(aux.givenName) \(aux.familyName)"
    contactsViewStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

}
```

Comment: Thats interesting! It made all the contacts appear but `Contact View` grew vertically upwards, hiding the above two UIView

Comment: Then you have your other constraints setup incorrectly. Make sure your "root" stack view does not have a height constraint set.